# Cannot add property to mongoose find object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting an object from the mongodb database and I would like to add an extra property to it before sending it to the frontend as a response (express).

```
obj = collection.find({});
obj[0].extra_property = "value";
res.send(obj);
```

I know that *obj* will also have some methods as properties (like $__version, increment,
$__where,
remove,
delete ...) but the object received in the frontend only contains the properties I defined in the mongodb schema, without those methods and without my added *extra_property*.

Could you show me a better method of returning the object and explain to me why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using mongoose, you can do `obj.toObject()` which would give you a vanilla JS object. In your case:

```
obj = collection.find({});
let toSend = obj.toObject();
toSend.extra_property = "value";
res.send(toSend);
```